# Implementing a swap method in a bubble sort

Tags: java, algorithm, bubble-sort

I have a program that I have written that allows the user to enter some votes into a system. In the end, the number entered correlates to the person of that number. (0 = Ahmed, 1 = boo, etc)

- 0 - Ahmed
- 1 - Boo
- 2 - Celine
- 3 - Didi
- 4 - Elaine

*(current)At the end of the voting period the program will sort the votes in descending order and output them (once the user has entered -1).*

*(future) the name of the candidate should be shown in this sorted list, e.g. ahmed - 5, celine - 4, didi -3, boo - 0, elaine - 0.*

I have the code writing the sorted vote numbers, but I am struggling to understand how it works to implement the swap with the name array to produce the final result as listed before in **future**.
Can anyone help with this? Below is my code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] NumArray = new int[5];
        final int EXIT_CODE = -1;
        displayInitialText();
        int userInput = input.nextInt();
        while (userInput != EXIT_CODE) {
            if (userInput >= 0 && userInput <= 4) {
                voteNumArray[userInput] = voteNumArray[userInput] + 1;
            } else {
                System.out.println("\n-----------------------");
                System.out.println("Invalid Vote - Please enter a number between 0-4");
                System.out.println("-----------------------\n");
            }
    
            userInput = input.nextInt();
        }
        sort(voteNumArray);
        displaySortedItems(voteNumArray);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bubble sort compares adjacent values and swaps if not in desired order so after every pass you will get largest/minimum(depending on implementation) value at the end of array.

let assume your array is having below values and you are sorting in ascending order -

```
2,5,1,7,4
```

In First pass, `i = 0` -

1. It will compare 2,5 and 5 is greater than 2, so no swap.
2. then it will compare 5,1 and 1 is smaller so it will swap and your array will become as below -

   2,1,5,7,4
3. compare 5,7 and no swap as 7 is greater.
4. compare 7,4 and swap as 4 is smaller and your array will become -

   2,5,1,4,7

After second pass, `i = 1` -

```
2,1,4,5,7
```

After third pass, `i = 2` -

```
1,2,4,5,7
```

Your array is sorted now, but still it will complete rest 2 passes but wont do any swap.

In every iteration you gets largest(considering ascending sorting) number in the end and thats the reason you are doing `j < array.length - i -1`, because you just need to sort remaining array.

Comment: okay, thanks for that, i understand better. In my code i have the variables i and j, what would you say is best to name them? so they have a better meaning.

Comment: Variable naming you can have as per your choice, even i and j also not bad and you will find same variable names mostly everywhere for bubble sort implementation. However if you want to change you can replace i -> pass and j -> index as i represents pass number and j represents index of array to access value.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a second swap function:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ... ...
        // ... ...

        sort(voteNumArray, voteNameArray); // Pass the second array too
        displaySortedItems(voteNumArray);
     }
     public static void sort(int[] array, String[] names){
        for (int i = 0; i < (array.length-1);i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < (array.length - i -1);j++){
                if(array[j] < array[j+1]){
                    swapInts(array,j);
                    swapStrings(names,j); // Swap in second array too
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static void swapInts(int[] array, int index){
        int temp = array[index];
        array[index] = array[index + 1];
        array[index + 1] = temp;
    }
    public static void swapStrings(String[] array, int index){ // Extra swap function
        String temp = array[index];
        array[index] = array[index + 1];
        array[index + 1] = temp;
    }
```